# NAT Gateway - how to find on router (regarding port forwarding)

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ssh, nat

I recently finished setting up SSH'ing to my Ubuntu-based server (thanks @Spiff) in terms of the port forwarding aspect. He told me that when remotely connecting, I need the router IP (aka NAT Gateway address). I have a Linksys EA7500. I went to Linksys Smart Wifi and opened the connections tab. I looked around to try and find something with NAT, when I came across the Advanced Routing tab. Heres a screenshot: [image: advanced routing screenshot] So what do I need to do to find this router address? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

You should indeed cross check it with one of the websites (e.g. just google "whatsmyip") that tells you your public IP. If they don't match, it means that you are probably sharing it with other customers of your ISP and hence cannot use it to connect to one of your machines. (It could be because you are chaining routers or so as well though.)

Comment: Thank you very much! This was exactly correct. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Go to http://ipchicken.com to see your external IP address.

Answer (score 1):

I said you need the public IP address of your NAT gateway/router. In other words, your Linksys EA7500's WAN IP address. From the screenshot you posted, I'm guessing it'll be on the "Internet Settings" tab.

Comment: I tried looking around, but couldn't find anything about the router's public IP. Sorry if that wasn't clear enough in my post. I'll check the Internet Settings tab again.